# how to just open a fancybox window (not onclick)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am triggering the fancybox to open `onclick` like this:

```
$('.telefonosOtrosPaises').fancybox({
                    'type'          :   'iframe',
                    'href'          :   'http://es.solmelia.com/nMenus/jsp/telefonosOtrosPaises.jsp',
                     'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
                    'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
                    /*'easingIn'      : 'easeInOutBack',

                    'easingOut'     : 'easeInOutBack',   */
                     /*onComplete : function(){ $('#fancybox-content').css({'height':'380px','width':'570px','background':'white','padding':'20px'})}*/
                     onComplete : function(){ $('#fancybox-content').css({'width':'630px','background':'white','paddingTop':'15px'})}
});
```

but how can i just open it in my js code when i need it?

Comment: See: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Comment: could you go into your profile and Mark some Answers to your previous questions as right please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of calling `.fancybox` on an element, call it like this:

```
$.fancybox.open(...)
```

**Note** this is fancybox 2 syntax, although it might work with v1

If you want to have it open on both `onclick` and when prompted in your code, just call `click` on the element you've attached it to.

```
$('.telefonosOtrosPaises').click();
```

Comment: Could you give some details about arguments! And how to ajax

Answer (score 1):

you can just call `yourControl.click()` to simulate a click event.

That way you can call it whenever you want it :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Fancybox's blog](http://fancybox.net/blog), you can try something like this:

```
$.fancybox(
    $('.telefonosOtrosPaises'), 
    {
        'type'          :   'iframe',
        'href'          :   'http://es.solmelia.com/nMenus/jsp/telefonosOtrosPaises.jsp',
         'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
        /*'easingIn'      : 'easeInOutBack',

        'easingOut'     : 'easeInOutBack',   */
         /*onComplete : function(){ $('#fancybox-content').css({'height':'380px','width':'570px','background':'white','padding':'20px'})}*/
         onComplete : function(){ $('#fancybox-content').css({'width':'630px','background':'white','paddingTop':'15px'})}
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very easily:

```
   <div id="divFancy" style="display: none;">
         FANCY BOX CONTENT GOES HERE
   </div>

    <script  type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.fancybox({
                'href': '#divFancy'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#target').click(function() {  
        $('.telefonosOtrosPaises').fancybox({
                        'type'          :   'iframe',
                        'href'          :   'http://es.solmelia.com/nMenus/jsp/telefonosOtrosPaises.jsp',
                         'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
                        'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
                        /*'easingIn'      : 'easeInOutBack',

                        'easingOut'     : 'easeInOutBack',   */
                         /*onComplete : function(){ $('#fancybox-content').css({'height':'380px','width':'570px','background':'white','padding':'20px'})}*/
                         onComplete : function(){ $('#fancybox-content').css({'width':'630px','background':'white','paddingTop':'15px'})}
        });
    });
});
</script>

<input type="button" id="target" value="press me"/>
</body>
</html>
```