# Open fancybox after condition with value read on .txt file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fancybox-2

I want to open a fancybox automatically when I enter the website and the value read on the txt file is "1"
The content of fancybox it will be a iframe to another page (alert.php)

To read the value of txt I have this

```
<?php
$line = file('alert.txt');
$valrec= $line[0]; //if "1" the fancybox appear
?>
```

I have difficulties using what I have read.

**Already Seen**

> [Open fancyBox automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537647/open-fancybox-automatically)
>
> [Open fancybox from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094233/open-fancybox-from-function)
>
> [how to just open a fancybox window (not onclick)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589881/how-to-just-open-a-fancybox-window-not-onclick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementing previous answers, you could do :

```
<?php
$line = file('alert.txt');
$valrec = $line[0]; //if "1" the fancybox appear
if($valrec == 1){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.fancybox({
        href: "alert.php",
        type: "iframe"
    });
}); //ready
</script>
<?php
}; // closes if
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $line = file('alert.txt');
    $valrec= $line[0]; 
    if($valrec=="1"){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fancybox('<?php echo $valrec;?>');
</script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: i used the code of JFK, but yor mworks to. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along the lines of this would work. Just echo the value of `$valrec` into your JavaScript so it can branch based on that value.

```
<?php
$line=file('alert.txt');
$valrec=$line[0];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {
              if(<?php echo($valrec); ?> === 1) $.fancybox("fancy box");
              else alert("lame box");
          });
</script>
```

If alert.txt contains "1", the above code sends the following HTML to the browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {
              if(1 === 1) $.fancybox("fancy box");
              else alert("lame box");
          });
</script>
```

If alert.txt contains "100", it sends this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {
              if(100 === 1) $.fancybox("fancy box");
              else alert("lame box");
          });
</script>
```